# what am i doing wrong? Code not going through. not returning second parameter

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

return single object.
return second parameter with first parameter values.
return parameter not hard coded.

```
function addPropertiesToObject(obj1, obj2) {
var param = {}
for (var things in obj1) {
    param[things] = obj1[things];
}
for (var things in obj2) {
    param[things] = obj2[things];
}
return param;
}
```

Comment: your code is taking two objects and merging the contents into one single object `param`. If both object has a same key eg `obj1 = {name: "John"}; obj2 ={name: "Jane"}`, Jane will overwrite John in your final result. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: i am trying to add obj1 to obj2 and return obj2

Answer (score 1):

Again, if both objects have the same key, that value will be overwritten by the second.

**Edit** to show adding `obj1` to `obj2` instead of `obj2` to `obj1`

```js
function addPropertiesToObject(obj1, obj2) {
  var param = {}
  for (var things in obj2) {
    param[things] = obj2[things];
  }
  for (var things in obj1) {
    param[things] = obj1[things];
  }
return param;
}

const obj1 = {name: "John"}
const obj2 = {name: "Jane"}
const obj3 = {email: "example@domain.com"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj2))
//Return: {name: "John"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj3))
//Return: {email: "example@domain.com", name: "John"}
```

You can also accomplish this without looping

```js
function addPropertiesToObject(obj1, obj2) {
return {...obj2,...obj1}
}

const obj1 = {name: "John"}
const obj2 = {name: "Jane"}
const obj3 = {email: "example@domain.com"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj2))
//Return: {name: "Jane"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj3))
//Return: {email: "example@domain.com", name: "John"}
```

If you would like to keep the contents of both objects, you can do something like:

```js
function addPropertiesToObject(obj1, obj2) {
  var param = {...obj2}
  for (var things in obj1) {
    if(param[things]) param[things] = [param[things], obj1[things]]
    else param[things] = obj1[things];
  }
return param;
}

const obj1 = {name: "John"}
const obj2 = {name: "Jane"}
const obj3 = {email: "example@domain.com"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj2))
//Return: {name: ["Jane","John"]}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj3))
//Return: {email: "example@domain.com", name: "John"}
```

Or changing the name of the key like:

```js
function addPropertiesToObject(obj1, obj2) {
  var param = {...obj2}
  for (var things in obj1) {
    if(param[things]) param[things+"1"] = obj1[things]
    else param[things] = obj1[things];
  }
return param;
}

const obj1 = {name: "John"}
const obj2 = {name: "Jane"}
const obj3 = {email: "example@domain.com"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj2))
//Return: {name: "Jane", name1: "John"}
console.log(addPropertiesToObject(obj1,obj3))
//Return: {email: "example@domain.com", name: "John"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object.assign(), Since this will copy the values from obj1 into obj2.

> Object.assign(obj1,obj2)

and return obj2